# (PHP) Should I create "triggers" in classes to access protected/private function?

Tags: php, class

I didn't find an answer to this question no where, so here it goes:

I normally create a protected/private function and public function as well to access the protected/private as a "trigger", is this a good practise or just a pointless excess of code?

Here is an example of what I'm talking about...

```
public function addData($data_c, $data_a)
{
    if ($this->isUser()) {
        $this->addDataDB($data_c, $data_a);
    } else {
        die;
    }
}

private function addDataDB($data_c, $data_a)
{
    $connect = self::connect_data();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `accounts`(...) VALUES (...)";

    $s_network = $data_c['s_network'];
    $country = $data_c['country'];
    $group_name = $data_c['group_name'];

    foreach ($data_a as $login_password) {

        $account = explode(':', $login_password);

        if (isset($account[0]) && !empty($account[0]) && isset($account[1]) && !empty($account[1])) {

            $login = $this->encryptData($account[0]);
            $password = $this->encryptData($account[1]);

            if (!$this->checkDuplicates($login)) {
                if ($stmt = $connect->prepare($sql)) {
                    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", ...);
                    $stmt->execute();
                }
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }
    }
    $connect->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not a bad idea, but the better way would be to create a new decorator class, which handles the secure access. In addition, it's a bad idea, to `die` - instead, you should throw an exception.

```
class A {
    function addData(...) {
        // ...
    }
}

class SecureA extends A {
    function addData {
        if (...) {
            throw new NotAllowedException(...);
        }
        parent::addData(...);
    }
}
```

If you want to go a step further and make you code more cleaner, you should use an interface and don't extend from class `A`

```
interface InterfaceA {
    function addData(...);
}

class A implements InterfaceA {
    function addData(...) {
        // ...
    }
}

class SecureAccessA implements InterfaceA {

    /**
     * @var InterfaceA
     */
    private $a;

    public function __construct(InterfaceA $a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    function addData(...) {
        if (...) {
            throw new NotAllowedException(...);
        }
        $this->a->addData(...);
    }
}
```

Doing this forces you to modify `SecureAccessA`, if you change the interface of `InterfaceA`. So you can't silently add functions to `A`, which are allowed to call, because you forgot to override them in the child class.